# Bash: sort numbers with exponents

Tags: bash, sorting, command-line

I was trying to sort one file with numeric values like this:

```
414e-05
435e-05
0.5361
0.7278
0.1341
0.9592
0.2664
```

With sort all the numers get sorted except for the ones with the exponent, is there some way for sort function to evaluate this expression?

Answer (score 40):

If your version of the sort command is new enough, it should support the <kbd>-g</kbd> option (or <kbd>--general-numeric-sort)</kbd> if you like your options long). It is described like this in the info manual:

> Sort numerically, using the standard C function `strtod` to
>   convert  a prefix of each line to a double-precision floating point
>   number. This allows floating point numbers to be specified in scientific
>   notation, like '1.0e-34' and '10e100'.

Comment: but -g seems not to sort a *mixture* of floating point numbers and scientific notation. I have sort 8.25 and it puts the two first numbers to the end.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I have a European locale.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough rep. to comment, so I am writing this to complement the accepted answer:

for those who have locales which use a comma instead of a period to indicate decimals, the sorting of decimals will not work properly, as pointed out by HongboZhu

Solution: the sorting of lists with period-delimited numbers will work properly when using something like the following command (important is the LC_ALL=C):

```
ls yourFolder|LC_ALL=C sort -g
```

This solution comes from the following post:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506965/bash-sort-g-does-not-work-properly

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have `sort -g`, an alternative you can get is [`scisort`](http://www.vanwal.nl/scisort/).

Comment: I have sort 8.23 and the "g" option doesn't work. @mob thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -e 'print sort { $a<=>$b } <>' < input-file
```