# sort data in scientific notation. sort -g does not work

Tags: sorting, unix, command-line

I meant to comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324923/bash-sort-numbers-with-exponents) but I lack the required reputation.
I need to sort data as the following block and `sort` would be just fine.
However, upon performing  `sort -g` on the following data I get the exact same figures - sorted if it weren't for the *e..*.

input and output:

```
0.00000000e+00
1.02272602e-02
1.25536099e-01
1.26666948e-02
1.29036099e-01
```

expected output

```
0.00000000e+00
1.02272602e-02
1.26666948e-02
1.25536099e-01
1.29036099e-01
```

Many thanks in advance!
Alternatives are welcome, though I will need to be able to sort by a specified column such as the second column in this block:

```
1.00000e+02, 0.00000000e+00
2.00000e+02, 1.02272602e-02
3.00000e+02, 1.25536099e-01
4.00000e+02, 1.26666948e-02
5.00000e+02, 1.29036099e-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> About you first question :

```
export LC_NUMERIC=en_US
sort -g data.txt
```

Test :

```
0.00000000e+00
1.02272602e-02
1.26666948e-02
1.25536099e-01
1.29036099e-01
```

> About your second question, to sort the second column :

```
export LC_NUMERIC=en_US
sort -k2.2,2.15g  data.txt
```

Test :

```
1.00000e+02, 0.00000000e+00
2.00000e+02, 1.02272602e-02
4.00000e+02, 1.26666948e-02
3.00000e+02, 1.25536099e-01
5.00000e+02, 1.29036099e-01
```

Explanations :

The LC_NUMERIC locale specifies the decimal-point character and thousands separator.